# ProjectReactor StepVerifier how to test expectNoEvent?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm having difficulties to verify expectNoEvent.

Considering the following code:

```
        StepVerifier.withVirtualTime((Supplier<Publisher<?>>) () -> Flux.just(1, 2, 3).cache(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(11))
            .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .verifyComplete();
```

It will always failed because there won't be any complete signal.

What is the best way to test noEvent?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to test here... `noEvent` is a concept of the `StepVerifier`. You are mixing `thenAwait()` that advances the (virtual) clock by a `Duration` but lets events percolate through and `expectNoEvent`, which also advances the (virtual) clock by a `Duration`, but fails whenever there is an event (onNext/onComplete/onError) within that duration.

Comment: Maybe the question should be rephrased "how to test cache method". Or how to test that the cache has expired

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747613/is-this-bug-in-flux-cachehistory-ttl