# Is this bug in Flux.cache(history, ttl)?

Tags: java, project-reactor

The following code

```
        StepVerifier.withVirtualTime((Supplier<Publisher<?>>) () -> Flux.just(1, 2, 3).cache(2, Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .expectNext(2, 3)
            .verifyComplete();
```

fails with exception

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(2)" failed (expected value: 2; actual value: 1)
```

If I change the expected values to

```
.expectNext(1, 2, 3)
```

it will pass. So it does not respect the `history` provided in `cache` method?

Answer (score 1):

Caching and TTL are a bit more tricky to test, because when you cache, what you want to test is what a **second** `Subscriber` sees. For the original cached `Flux`, the `cache` operator is just pass-through. This first pass is what `StepVerifier` tested (it performed the first subscription).

In order to fix that, simply extract the `Supplier` and `subscribe` immediately inside the supplier:

```
Supplier<Flux<Integer>> supplier = () -> {
        Flux<Integer> tested = Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
                                   .cache(2, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                                   .log();
        tested.subscribe();
        return tested;
    };

StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(supplier)
            .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .expectNext(2, 3)
            .verifyComplete();
```

This tests that the history limit of the cache is respected.

The TTL is yet another thing. It is not an expiry on cached items for later replay but rather a condition on whether or not to cache an item, according to the arrival "rythm" of the source. So it is more dependent on the source having delays in its emissions. See the tests in [`FluxCacheTest`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/src/test/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxCacheTest.java) and how they use `delayElements` for that.

Comment: But then how to test that after 10 seconds there is nothing in the cache?

Comment: @wins don't hesitate to come discuss your questions and your project on Reactor gitter channel btw ;p

Comment: Never use that before. Will try that